# On representability of $\underline{Hom}_k(\mathbb A^1_k, \mathbb A^1_k)$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, schemes, representable-functor

Let $F:k\text{-Sch} \rightarrow \text{Set}$ be the following functor:

$$F(X)=\text{Hom}_{X-\text{sch}}(\mathbb A^1_X, \mathbb A^1_X).$$

I would like to show that such functor is not representable.

I am able to show that is not representable by an affine scheme. Indeed, suppose $X=\text{Spec }R$ represents such functor and let $p(x)\in \text{Hom}_{X-\text{sch}}(\mathbb A^1_X, \mathbb A^1_X)=R[x]$ the universal object. If $A$ is a $k$-algebra and $a(x)\in A[x]$, then it should exist a morphism of $k$-algebras $R\rightarrow A$, such that the induced morphism $R[x]\rightarrow A[x]$ maps $p(x)$ to $a(x)$. If the degree of $p(x)$ is smaller than the one of $a(x)$, then it is impossible. Such argument could be extented to prove that such functor it is not representable by a quasi-compact scheme, but I'm not able to do the general case.

Any hints or ideas?

Comment: I agree: I can prove that it’s not representable by a finite-type scheme over $ \mathbb{Z} $ by essentially the same argument as yours but I don’t know what to do if it gets too pathological. I think we need some finiteness assumption - that the representing object has a finite cover by open affines.

Answer (score 2):

This functor is not an algebraic space. In particular, it is not representable by a scheme. This is pointed out by Jason Starr in his comment [here,](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/290518/representable-texthom-functors) and proved in Claim 3.1 of his paper "Artin's axioms, composition and moduli spaces".

The idea is the following:

If $F$ is an algebraic space, then the tangent space at the $k$-point $id$ corresponding to identity morphism is countably infinite-dimensional.
This is implicit in your argument: any of the $a(x)$ in $k[x]$ determines a tangent vector at the $id$, and vice versa. Therefore the tangent space at $id$ is isomorphic to $k[x]$ as a $k$-vector space, which is countably infinite-dimensional.

On the other hand, for an algebraic space, if the tangent space at a $k$-point is infinite-dimensional, it must be uncountably infinite. This is because the tangent space is defined as the dual of the cotangent space, and the dual of an infinite dimensional vector space is uncountably infinite-dimensional.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1942016)

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I clarified that if a functor is not an algebraic space, then it is not representable by any scheme. This addresses the exact question.

Comment: Why did you write then that “[t]his should really be a comment, not an answer”?

Comment: Oh, I don't feel this is significant enough to be an answer. Let me remove that line, if that sounds offensive or inappropriate.